# Visual c++ operation of swprintf

Tags: c++

I have a routine in which I call swprintf.  From all the documentation that I have found, it is supposed to work like sprintf, only with Unicode strings.  However, the code

```
swprintf(buffer, wcslen(buffer), L"COM %d", i );
```

removes the number of letters determined by i.  If i = 0 buffer = "COM0"; if i = 1, buffer = "COM"; if i = 2, buffer = "CO" - etc.

Does anybody have an explanation???  The complete code is shown below

```
void SelectComPort() //added function to find the present serial 
{
wchar_t lpTargetPath[5000]; // buffer to store the path of the COMPORTS
wchar_t buffer[20];
DWORD test;
bool gotPort=0; // in case the port is not found
size_t  size = 0;

for(int i=0; i<255; i++) // checking ports from COM0 to COM255
{
    swprintf(buffer, wcslen(buffer), L"COM %d", i );
    test = QueryDosDevice(buffer, &lpTargetPath[size], 5000);

        // Test the return value and error if any
    if(test != 0) //QueryDosDevice returns zero if it didn't find an object
    {
        size = wcslen(lpTargetPath);
        gotPort=1; // found port
    }

    if(::GetLastError()==ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
    {
        lpTargetPath[10000]; // in case the buffer got filled, increase size    of the buffer.
        continue;
    }

}

return;
```

}

Comment: `wcslen` returns the length of the *string*, not the length of the *buffer*.   Try `swprintf(buffer, 20, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

`swprintf` takes the length of the *buffer* as an argument, not the length of the *string*.  `wsclen` will return once it encounters a null character in the buffer.  Calling `wcslen` on an uninitialized buffer is definitely undefined behavior because there's a very good chance that the pointer will get incremented out of the array bounds searching for the terminating null.

Instead of calling `wcslen`, use the length of the array itself, i.e. 20.

Also: the `COM#` ports do not have a space between `COM` and the number.

Comment: The problem was the wsclen - put in proper buffer length and it worked fine.   Many thanks for the catch.  Sorry but I have been getting frustrated with using Visual C++ that I am making silly mistakes